# How can I use two different Custom UITableViewCell's in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have two custom UITableViewCell's. Let's call them cellA, and cellB. They are very similar. Both have **title**, **subtitle**, and **image** view's placed in the exact same spot. However, the cellB also has an additional **date** label.

Now, each of these custom cell's are in their own nib files.

1) To register them both, would you do the following code, or should they both be placed in the same nib file?

```
UINib *cellANib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CellACell" bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:cellANib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ACell"];
UINib *cellBNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CellBCell" bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:cellBNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"BCell"];
```

2) In cellForRowAtIndexPath, I will be using either CellA or CellB based on the data. Should I fork the entire method with one huge if statement, or how can I call `cell.title.text =` without casting the cell in an if statement. Like...

```
if (data.type == DATA_TYPE_A) {
    ((CellACell *)cell).title.text = data.title;
}
else {
    ((CellBCell *)cell).title.text = data.title;
}
```

How can I avoid such a mess? Can I make both cells extend an interface type class or something, so I don't need to cast, or fork the entire method with a huge if statement?

**EDIT:**

I think "hiding the labels" that are unused would be best. How can I achieve hiding them? I oversimplified for the question, but I have 4 views horizontally across. [---[1]-[----2----]-[3]-[----4----]---]. I have label's 1 and 3 fixed. 1 is fixed to the leading superview. 3 is fixed Center X to something else on the cell. Now for A-Data, it only needs to use labels 1/2. B-Data needs to use 1/2/3/4. For A data, I would then like to hide labels 3 and 4, and 2 should expand to the right where 4 ends. How can I achieve this hiding of labels 3 and 4?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly build 2 different interfaces in 2 different xibs, but have both cells be the same custom class. You would have all the IBOutlets for all the UI elements in both cells, and just hook up the ones that are present in the particular interface. In cellForRowAtIndexPath, you would need an if-else clause to dequeue the appropriate cell for particular index paths, and only the date label would need to be populated within the if-else. The other labels could be populated outside, since both cells would have the appropriate outlets, and there would be no need for casting. The way you're doing the registering of the xibs is fine.

Another possibility would be to just have one xib with all the labels, and hide the one you don't want in the rows where you don't have a date value.

Comment: I added a short EDIT to my original post. Do you mind checking it out and explaining how I might hide certain labels?

Comment: @chrisP, you can't do that (easily anyway) by hiding labels; hiding does not cause the constraints to go away. I would just go with the 2 different versions of the cell approach.

Answer (score 0):

There are many answers to your questions. You could just use CellA for everything and hide the date label where appropriate. You could make two methods called `configureCellA(...)` and `configureCellB(...)` that you can call in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath(...)` if statements; that will cut down on the clutter of that particular method. You could setup inheritance so that they both have the regular labels and a subclass as a date label. You have lots of options.

EDIT: To hide labels 3/4 and have labels 1/2 fill out the rest of the space, you could set `label.hidden = true` and make a `CGRect` that is the same as the label you are hiding, except set the `width` to `0`. Assuming you are using autolayout, the labels will expand.

Comment: I added a short EDIT to my original post. Do you mind checking it out and explaining how I might hide certain labels?

Answer (score 0):

For just hiding the date you can do the following
You can, have a class from UITableViewCell linked to the Cell in Storyboard, and all your IBoutlets in that class inherited from UITableViewCell

inside you would have a function to set up the data and populate so your Class header would be

```
// MySpecialTableCellClass.h

@interface MySpecialTableCellClass : UITableViewCell

-(void)setDataForCellWithTitle:(NSString *)title subTitle:(NSString *)subtitle image:(UIImage *)cellImage date:(NSDate *)cellDate;

@end
```

in your source file

```
@interface MySpecialTableCellClass ()

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField *title;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField *subTitle;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageDisplay;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField *date;

@end

@implementation MySpecialTableCellClass

-(void)setDataForCellWithTitle:(NSString *)title subTitle:(NSString *)subtitle image:(UIImage *)cellImage date:(NSDate *)cellDate 
{
     [self.title setText:title];
     [self.subTitle setText:subtitle];  
     self.imageDisplay.image = cellImage;

     if(cellDate != nil)
     {
         NSString *dateString = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:[NSDate date]                                                dateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle                                                       timeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
         [self.date setText:dateString];
     }
     else
     {
          //Hide it if the date was not found
          self.date.hidden = YES;
     }


}
@end
```

and in your Cell for Row function

```
//Get the data from your element including image and date if needed
MySpecialTableCellClass *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"CellIdentifier"];
[cell setDataForCellWithTitle:title subTitle:subtitle image:cellImage date:cellDate];
return cell;
```

Comment: You can use this same methodology if you want to go for two different cells, your parent class would be this class and your inherited would over ride the function for data with date and without date